# Comparation of two sets that use cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are sets and $C = \{ S \times T : (S,T) \in \mathcal P(A) \times \mathcal P(B)\}$, are $P(A \times B)$ and $C$ are always equal? Is one always a subset of the other or there is no "⊆" relation between them?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried some examples?

Comment: Actually the exercise is asking $\mathcal{P}(A)\times\mathcal{P}(B)\overset{?}{\subseteq}\mathcal{P}(A\times B)$. So, **hint**: Take an element from the first set, do the math and check if it also belongs to the other set. If it doesn't work out, check the other way around.

Comment: @frabala: The exercise is asking no such thing. See my comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, $C$ is the set of Cartesian products $S\times T$ where $S\subseteq A$ and $T\subseteq B.$ Take any $S\times T\in C.$ If $(x,y)\in S\times T,$ then $x\in S\subseteq A$ and $y\in T\subseteq B,$ so $x\in A$ and $y\in B,$ so $(x,y)\in A\times B$. Hence, $S\times T\subseteq A\times B,$ and so $S\times T\in\mathcal P(A\times B).$ This holds for all $S\times T\in C,$ so that $C\subseteq\mathcal P(A\times B).$

The reverse inclusion need not hold in general, and will *fail* to hold precisely when $A,B$ both have more than one element. In particular, suppose $a_1,a_2\in A$ are distinct and $b_1,b_2\in B$ are distinct. Now consider the set $\bigl\{(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2)\bigr\}.$ Does this set lie in $C$? In $\mathcal P(A\times B)$?

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect.  $\mathcal{P}(A \times B)$ is not equivalent to $\mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B)$.  One counterexample is as follows:

Let $A = \{a\}$ and $B = \{b\}$.  We have $A \times B = \{(a,b)\}$.  Then, $\mathcal{P}(A \times B) = \{\varnothing, \{(a,b)\}\}$.

For $\mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B)$... we have $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{\varnothing, \{a\}\}$ and $\mathcal{P}(B) = \{\varnothing, \{b\}\}$  Then,

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B) &= \{(a,b): a \in \mathcal{P}(A), b \in \mathcal{P}(B)\}\\
&= \{(\varnothing, \varnothing), (\varnothing, \{b\}), (\{a\}, \varnothing), (\{a\}, \{b\})\}
\end{aligned}$$

So we conclude that $\mathcal{P}(A \times B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B)$

Comment: But $(\emptyset,\emptyset)=(\emptyset,\{b\})=(\{a\},\emptyset)=\emptyset$. So, $\mathcal{P}(A\times B)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(A)\times\mathcal{P}(B)$ after all.

Comment: Certainly.  I will make the adjustment of my answer.

Comment: $\mathcal P(A \times B)$ is not a subset of $\mathcal P(A) \times \mathcal P(B)$ in your example.

Comment: @frabala: What? Those are distinct ordered pairs, and none is equal to the empty set (for any construction of ordered pairs *I'm* familiar with, anyway).

Comment: @NasuSama: Observe that $\mathcal P(A)\times\mathcal P(B)$ is *not* the same as $$C=\bigl\{S\times T:(S,T)\in\mathcal P(A)\times\mathcal P(B)\bigr\}.$$